# Allowing rectangle to be clickable - android

Tags: android

I wrote a View with canvas, which contains many rectangles. I want these rectangles to be used as a button which will open a new activity. How can I do it?

Comment: Are any of these answers helpful?

Comment: Thank you all for helping. I succeed creating clickable rectangles, but if the rectangle is small, it's very difficult to click on it (only after 5-6 click attempts)

Comment: @LiorZ Hai can you provide working code for this?

Answer (score 11):

You need to be careful with Suri Sahani example, onTouchEvent is called on any action qualified as a touch event, meaning press, release, movement gesture, etc([Android Event Listener Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners)). To use the onTouchEvent properly you need to check the MotionEvent type.

```
List<Rect> retangles;//Assume these have been drawn in your draw method.

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int touchX = event.getX();
    int touchY = event.getY();
    switch(event){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            System.out.println("Touching down!");
            for(Rect rect : rectangles){
                if(rect.contains(touchX,touchY)){
                    System.out.println("Touched Rectangle, start activity.");
                    Intent i = new Intent(<your activity info>);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            System.out.println("Touching up!");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            System.out.println("Sliding your finger around on the screen.");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When you use `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` **float** values are returned, so you must type-cast `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` to **int** for use with int-type variables. Also, `event` in the `switch` statement should be `event.getAction()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onTouchEvent()` just capture the x and y values and you can use the `contains(int x, int y)` method in the `Rect` class. If `contains(x, y)` returns true, then the touch was inside the rectangle and then just create the intent and start the new activity.