# Attaching Click-Handler to canvas.drawRect() Object

Tags: android

I am coding a tetris like game and am wondering if there is an easier way to track clicks.

The game board is a 6 by 8 grid of rectangles.  I have a class `GameBoard` that extends `View`.  Here I override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method and draw the board via a bunch of  `canvas.drawRect(30,30,80,80,paint)` calls.

Is there an easy way to hook up a handler to tell me which rectangle has been clicked?  In .net you can use rect.contains(Point p).

Or am I just stuck doing the mat to figure out what rectangle a given point is in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `rect.contains(int x, int y)` inside an `onTouch()` to find it.

Android Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains(int,int)

SO answers: "In your `onTouchEvent()` just capture the x and y values and you can use the `contains(int x, int y)` method in the Rect class. If `contains(x, y)` returns true, then the touch was inside the rectangle and then just create the intent and start the new activity."

from [Allowing rectangle to be clickable - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258146/allowing-rectangle-to-be-clickable-android)

Also: [Android: How to check if a path contains touched point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588003/android-how-to-check-if-a-path-contains-touched-point)

Comment: Aw I see.  So I'd use the `canvas.drawRect(rectObject, paint) and just store the Rect objects somewhere. Literally exactly the same as .NET.  Thanks buddy!